# Tableview cell automaticDimension for 3 labels with one container view

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, autolayout

[image]

The white background is my cell super view and the blue background view is the container view. The container view is connected with the super view with the following constraints.

`Top space to super view: 25, Bottom space to super view: 12`

In the container view (Blue view) there are 3 labels.
`Weekly plan, Monthly plan, Save about...`

The `Weekly plan label` has a height constraint of `height >= 22` and it has a top space with its `container view` (Blue view) which is 16 and the bottom space with the `monthly label` is 10. The monthly view has a 0 bottom constraint with the `save about` label. And finally the `save about label` has 12 bottom constraints with the `container view`.

These 3 labels could have multiple lines and I need to show them accordingly. If one line then it will show in 1 line if multiple lines then it will show all text in multiple lines.

Right now I am trying to show them with `UITableView.automaticDimension` inside of the table view `heightForRowAt` delegate.

`case .weeklyPlan, .monthlyPlan, .annualPlan: return UITableView.automaticDimension`

But it's not updating all cells properly. I didn't set any estimated row height or any other height ratio in my view did load. What I am missing here?

Comment: Are you laying this out in Storyboard? Or all in code?

Answer (score 0):

in order to make it work, you should use preferredMaxLayoutWidth on the labels. This property set the preferred maximum width for a multiline label.

This would be an example on what you should put in the tableViewCell awakeFromNib() method.

```
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    subtitleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    titleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = frame.width
    subtitleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = frame.width
    descriptionLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = frame.width

    containerView.clipsToBounds = true
    containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
    containerView.backgroundColor = .cyan
```

Answer (score 0):

First make `numberOfLines = 0` to your labels and if you dont make any constraint `(leading , trailing)` to your labels even if you set `numberOfLines to 0` the texts will not go into the 2nd paragraph.Texts will overflow from the label , you will see it with three dots at the point where it overflows.

It's hard to tell without seeing the code but
giving `leading and trailing constraints` will fix your issue.